# Lightbox is downloading the image Instead of displaying the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, lightbox2

I am using angular, bootstrap and lightbox.
I have added the following js and css files for lightbox:

```
<script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
```

and then I added the following code:

```
<a href="{{data.ImageUrl}}" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><button ng-click="viewImage(message)">view</button></a>
```

just like how they have said here : [lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
But that is not working as I wanted. It display the view button when I click on that. It display an image with zoom and then when I click that again It display that image in a light box.
I also tried other method which was mentioned [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3881276). I added this to my code

```
<a href="{{data.imageUrl}}" rel="lightbox" ><button ng-click="viewImage(message)">view</button></a>
```

even that worked the same way.

I am new to angular and all the stuff mentioned above.
{{data.imageUrl}} contains the url of the image. 

 I tried alot to make it work. But still this is not working. sometime It display nothing and other times it display image with zoom and then when I click on that it display that image in lightbox which is not what I want and sometime it just download the image.(this things happens when I do any change to the code)

I want that when I click on the view button. It should popUp a lightBox with the image mentioned in {{data.message}}.
Can someone help me with this. I want to know did I missed something or what is did is completely wrong.

the viewImage(message) is a controller which takes the message as input and set value for data.imageUrl to imageUrl which I want to display

How should I use lightbox?. Thanks If someone can help me with this. Thank you so much guys.


**[edit 1]**:
I am adding my code so that it can help you guys find the mistake done by me. Your feedback are most needed to me. Thanks Guys.
This is my current code after all edits :
Html code:

```html
<a href="{{message.securePicUrl}}" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">View</a>


<!-- second version 
<a href="{{message.securePicUrl}}" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">View</a>
-->
```

The message contains details about the message. The {{message.securePicUrl}} is the url of the image I want to display.


My previous code looked something like this:

```js
$scope.showFullImage = function(message) {
        console.log("Show Full Image : ");
        console.log(message);
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template: '<img src="{{details.securePicUrl}}">',
            controller: 'displayImagePopup',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve:{
                messageDetails: function(){
                    return message;
                }
            }
        });
    }


//.... some code here....

//controller
myApp.controller('displayImagePopup', function ($scope, $modalInstance, messageDetails) {
    $scope.details = messageDetails;
    $scope.imageCaption = "";
    if (messageDetails.picCaption)
        $scope.imageCation = messageDetails.picCaption;
    console.log(messageDetails);
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

```html
<!-- code to display the image -->

<a class="pos-abs btn-view btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); showFullImage(message)" ng-attr-data-lightbox="{(message.messageType == 3 || message.messageType == 5) ? message.messageId:null}">View</a>


<!-- some code here -->

 <!-- full size image viewer-->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="displayImagePopup.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img ng-src="{{details.securePicUrl}}" alt="{{imageCaption}}">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </script>
```

This 2nd snippet is the one which displayed a modal containing an image. But I wanted to display the image in lightbox so I made changes to my code (you can see 1st snippet for that)

**[edit 1]**: added more code snippets.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used lightbox, but, if you want to bind href with angularjs, you should do like:

```
<a ng-href="{{some-var-inscope}}" ...>
```

Comment: ok, I would like to to help, but failed to create a example on plunker, can you provide a example?